# Android Trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":

Tags: android

I have an Android Project in which I need to work with .ods file. I have found the simple API of [Apache odf toolkit](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/index.html)

I have include to my project with that line:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.odftoolkit', name: 'simple-odf', version: '0.8.1-incubating'
```

It build correctly, but when I run, I have the following error:

```
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

I saw on several topic of this error that I need to exclude several modules so I have tried this:

```
compile (group: 'org.apache.odftoolkit', name: 'simple-odf', version: '0.8.1-incubating'){
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
```

But this doesn't work.

Does anyone have a solution for me?